# How many space launch vehicles are under development worldwide?

Tags: launch-vehicle

I need to know how many space launch vehicles (across categories - small, medium , heavy etc) are under development, worldwide.

For instance this [report](https://spacenews.com/foust-forward-worldwide-there-are-131-small-launch-vehicles-in-the-works-most-of-these-will-fizzle-out/) talks only about the number of Small Space Launch Vehicles that are under development. However, I could not find the figures for Medium Space Launch Vehicles, Heavy Space Launch Vehicles among others.

Is there any authoritative source where this figure is available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't an authoritative source.

The 131 small launchers mentioned in the article you linked, are from "a long-running effort to track small launch vehicle efforts" -- but won't include any that they haven't heard of. The [2018 list and its criteria](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4118&context=smallsat) includes the ominous phrase "We  have  found  out  about  many  of  these 
vehicles by word of mouth from readers of our previous 
papers."

However, anything other than a small launch vehicle is likely to be too expensive to develop privately, so there are likely less than a dozen under development in any of the other weight classes.

Wikipedians appear to have given up tracking them. The forum at NasaSpaceFlight is a good place to look. The CIA probably have the best list.

Comment: Is the downvoter aware of an authorative list?

Comment: Hah! Submit a FOIA request for the CIA's recon data ;).

Comment: To help reinforce the futility of even attempting to establish a 'complete list' of what is 'in development': Myself and a group of friends have been competing with each other to design functional micro-sats and launchers, and I don't think any of them are public projects. At best we could hope to maintain lists of projects that have achieved official flight status or openly announced development, as I alone have nearly a dozen launchers in pre-flight status [that are in various stages of abandonment...]

Answer (score 2):

It's virtually impossible to keep track of all the small launch vehicles.

Most of the big ones are included at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems

Vehicles still in development are listed in tan colour.

Note that retired launchers are in a separate table at the bottom, so don't go looking for the Saturn V in the top table.